# setprecision and string namespace

Tags: c++, include, precision, stdstring

How come when I do

```
using std::string;
```

I get an error but after I include string, it doesn't throw error. Same with `std::setprecision`.

```
#include <string>
using std::string; //Throws error when string library not included
#include <iomanip>
using std::setprecsion; //Throw error when iomanip library not included

int main()
{
    //stuff
}
```

When I leave out the `#include` preprocessor, why does it throw an error saying `string` or `setprecision` is not part of `std namespace`, but when I add the libraries they don't? Do they somehow get added to std namespace after including the libraries?

Would it kind of be like bracket notation in *JavaScript*?

```
var obj = {
    one: 1
};

obj['two'] = 2;
```

Comment: Because `std::string` has not been declared before you include the header which declares it.

Comment: So importing the string from the <string> library adds it to the std namespace?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. C++ relies on the preprocessor to share declarations.

Comment: Looks like you're maybe coming from a Java background.  Be aware that you don't need to have the `using` statements at all.  All that does is import that type into your namespace.  It's preferable, in my opinion, to just get into the habit of typing `std::string` everywhere instead of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because the functions you are trying to use are defined in their library files. In C , C++ you have to write **#include**  to include the library in your program and use its functions.